# A word for someone who only sees you as one thing

Tags: word-request

It could be your personality or maybe a physical trait that you have. I'm going to try to give an example.

For instance:

You're a **gay** man, and people around you don't see you as a human being anymore, they simply define you and only see you as gay. You're nothing but a gay man.

Comment: An example of a sentence you could use it in would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## reductionist

"reductionism" from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reductionism):

> **2 :** a procedure or theory that reduces complex data and phenomena to simple terms

To think of a gay man only as a gay man is *reductionist* thinking. It ignores all other facets of his personality and identity and reduces him to one aspect of who he is.

Comment: There it is!! That's the word I was looking for!!! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The one that immediately springs to mind is

#### [Stereotype](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stereotype)

From the Cambridge dictionary…

> **a set idea that people have about what someone or something is like, especially an idea that is wrong:**
>
> racial/sexual stereotypes
> He doesn't conform to/fit/fill the national stereotype of a Frenchman.
> The characters in the book are just stereotypes.
> I think I fit the popular stereotype of a mad scientist.
> She was the very stereotype of the prim English woman.
> Adverts are full of stereotypes.
> The latest series contains a thoroughly offensive stereotype of a gay man.
> Her plots are predictable and her characters little more than stereotypes.

The 'action' would be stereotyping. I'm not sure of it as a description of a person who stereotypes, stereotyper or stereotypist;) don't really work for me.

See also [Wikipedia - stereotype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereotype)

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I really appreciate your help, but that is not the word that I'm looking for. I would say that the word I'm searching for is related to: reduce, minimize, diminish, dilute, make less, maybe concentrate and condense etc...

Comment: @studentxxy In your question, you ask for a word about the *person*, which would be a noun or adjective, but here you're listing verbs, which might describe that person's *behaviour*. Which do you want? As the comment on the question has said, an example sentence -- even one with a blank where the word would go -- would be helpful

Comment: @gotube - tbh I'm really struggling for anything between 'stereotype' as the 'victim' & what feels like a big jump all the way to 'bigot' as the accuser. It seems a step too far.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like *one-dimensional*? Though I’d rather use that to describe the person’s attitude than the person themselves. The latter would seem to one-dimensionalize (?) them.